# How shall I arrange my slowly-eating plan and preserve a box of 5Lb frozen eggs over a long period?

Tags: storage-method, eggs, frozen

I have a box of 5Lb of frozen eggs with citric acid, where

> 1 Lb is 9 large eggs
>
> Unopened product should be used within 3 days of thrawing.
>
> Unused portion should be kept refrigerated and used within 24 hours of
>   opening

I can't eat all after thrawing and opening it. I can only eat 1 egg i.e. 3 table spoon per day. How shall I arrange my slowly-eating plan and store the remaining  frozen eggs over a long period?

[image] [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would thaw one pound, and make something with it that I can freeze. For example. I bake quiches in leek and chard season - each quiche uses three eggs. They freeze beautifully once cooked (I slice them into servings before I freeze them) and it's easy to remove one slice, warm it in the microwave, and enjoy. So make three quiches and freeze them, you could eat two slices a day if you wanted to.

You could experiment with a variety of egg dishes that are not just "one egg, scrambled", or "one egg, fried" to use 9 eggs at a time. The internet is full of recipes for frittatas, quiches, soufflees, egg casseroles, and the like. Just remember to cook your creations before freezing, and to partition them for serving.

Comment: Tortilla (Spanish omelette) freezes well and is another to add to the list. You'd need a big freezer to get many portions in but you might also try pasta carbonara. Cake freezes OK too. But many egg-based foods are quite prone to freezer burn.

Comment: How do you go about thawing 1 pound?

Answer (score 3):

Probably the most useful idea is to thaw the whole box, and promptly open it and refreeze in single-egg sized, or divisible into single-egg sized portions (maybe using an ice cube tray? three, one tbs cubes per "egg").  Frozen egg cubes can probably be packed in the box again for storage purposes - or else some freezer-safe container, clearly labeled.  You might wait until you have some egg-intensive need (baking day?) that will let you use up a fair portion of the product all at once - and recall that egg cooked into something will have its own safe storage times, likely longer than just the 24 hours if properly stored.

Once the box is thawed and opened, you have twenty four hours before it needs to be used - that can include refreezing (which pauses the time spent), as long as you remember that the time that has passed is still gone - ie, assume your re-frozen egg portions are only good for 20 hours in the fridge after re-thawing, if it took you 4 hours to freeze all the egg.

Of course, if you really don't want to thaw and re-portion before re-freezing, the only other option I can think of is to very carefully cut the box off of the still-frozen eggs, and while keeping it very cold (intermittently sticking back in the freezer if it looks like it's thawing?), cut into smaller, more manageable cubes freehand, then quickly pack up and store in the freezer again.

Also worth pointing out - you can cook with the egg, and keep the products for longer than just the egg.  Foods kept in the fridge usually have 5-7 days, I think, but you can freeze foods that have been cooked with egg as well, nearly indefinitely.  It likely won't use up your five pounds, unless you do a major holiday baking day to feed the whole family plus gifts, but it may use up a fair portion and *then* you can refreeze the rest.

Comment: Considering the text "shake well before using" I'm not sure how homogeneous the mixture is while frozen so I'm not sure if cutting it up without defrosting is going to work.

Comment: @Catija - fair point, but I suppose it would depend on how non-homogeneous it looks after the box is opened if someone would like to try that way anyway.  Or, of course, they can thaw it first.  Or maybe slushy the stuff and refreeze it from partially frozen, that might let you mix it without thawing

Comment: I had read you are not supposed to refreeze raw protiens. http://www.thekitchn.com/5-foods-you-should-never-refreeze-tips-from-the-kitchn-212039

Comment: Thanks. does your last paragraph suggest me to cook all in the box, divide the cooked eggs into portions per day, and re-freeze them?

Comment: @Paparazzi - It looks like that's mostly a texture thing, which I don't think will apply to already-frozen eggs - egg's texture changes dramatically with cooking, unlike frozen meats.  And even that link says that it may be safe to refreeze if thawed in the fridge, just perhaps with poorer texture.

Comment: @Tim - you can do it that way, if you know how you are going to want to cook the eggs and are prepared to do all the cooking for the whole batch at once.  Mostly I was suggesting using as large a portion of your eggs as you can figure out how in this manner, and re-freezing the rest - since I can't think of much I'd want to cook that much egg's worth at once.

Answer (score 1):

You have 45 eggs and can only eat one per day.  By the rules you would only be able to eat 2 (consume open within 24 hours).

I assume the 24 hours is based on oxygen contact.  Let's say it thaws in 1 day then quickly pour some off in a small container you fill up so there is no oxygen.  You should be able to get a full 3 days out of that but then you are still only up to 4 days.

Cook what is left over from the first and freeze 2-3 day portions.  According to this can get 4 months.   [how to freeze cooked eggs](https://www.leaf.tv/articles/how-to-freeze-scrambled-eggs/)

Comment: Your assumption that it is "based on oxygen contact" is wrong. As soon as you introduce potential contamination (open the container) the clock starts ticking.

Comment: @rumtscho Really?   I have a degree in chemical engineering.  Time to contaminates  and  volume of contaminates are big big factors.

Comment: And there is a difference between chemical engineering and public health legislation.

Comment: @rumtscho Now this is legislative issue?

Comment: Yes - food safety is a mixture of epidemiology, sociology and law. Or maybe I should say "science communication" instead of "sociology", or in addition to it - the lines are blurry. Chemical reaction are usually disregarded, except in some rare cases.